# componentDidUpdate Conversion to Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-hooks

I would like to rewrite this life cycle metod into a hook:

```
componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    const { notifications, popNotification } = this.props;

    if (prevProps.notifications.length >= notifications.length) return;

    const [notification] = notifications;
    popNotification(notification.id);
    this.setState({
        open: true,
        message: notification.text,
        variant: notification.variant,
    });
};
```

I know that I have to use an useEffect hook but it didn't get it working until now. This is what I came up so far:

```
function usePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
}

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const popMessage = useCallback(id =>
    dispatch(NotificationActions.popNotification(id))
);

const notifications = useSelector(state => state.notifications);
const previousValue = usePrevious(notifications.length);

useEffect(() => {
    if (previousValue >= notifications.length) return;

    // Extract notification from list of notifications
    const [notification] = notifications;
    popMessage(notification.id);
    // Open snackbar
    setSnackbar({
        open: true,
        message: notification.text,
        variant: notification.variant,
    });
});
```

This attempt doesn't work as the old method, it gets called more than the old method and also throws a `TypeError: notification is undefined`. In addition, if I add a `if (notifications.length > 0)` before the extraction of the notification, it is still not working.

Comment: Don't you need to add `[value]` in the useEffect of your usePrevious? Something like this: `useEffect(() => { ... }, [value])`. Also in the other useEffect, I think you should add `[notifications]` to your useEffect. At least this shouldn't get called more than the old one.

Comment: Take a look at usePrevious here: https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Couple of issues</strike> One issue I can see with your Hook code:

1. <strike>`usePrevious` will never update beyond the first value set</strike>

   When no dependencies are set in `useEffect` then it runs once and once only. In your case, because you want to keep track of the last value set you need to make this a dependency of `useEffect` i.e. `useEffect(() => ..., [value])`, this will force the callback to re-run and update the ref.

   *Turns out I misunderstood that when the function component re-renders, it re-runs the effects for hooks, you can ignore point 1.*
2. The main update code inside `useEffect`, similar to point 1, will only run once.

   Again, the code is expected to re-run when the notification count has changed and therefore needs to be set as a dependency `useEffect(() => ..., [notifications.length])`

As for the error you mention - `notification is undefined`, this suggests that your `notifications` state either isn't a valid array or the array is empty, check the result of `useSelector(state => state.notifications)`

Here's how I'd expect it to look based on your code

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const popMessage = useCallback(id =>
  dispatch(NotificationActions.popNotification(id))
, []);

const notifications = useSelector(state => state.notifications);
const previousValue = usePrevious(notifications.length);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!notifications.length || previousValue >= notifications.length) return;

  // Extract notification from list of notifications
  const [notification] = notifications;
  if (!notification) return;

  popMessage(notification.id);
  // Open snackbar
  setSnackbar({
    open: true,
    message: notification.text,
    variant: notification.variant,
  });
}, [notifications]);
```

Comment: Well, thank you for updating the answer and helping me. I did it in a different way but both versions are fine. Can you also delete all your comments under your answer? I already deleted mine for a better readability.

Comment: @Peter I just followed the same early exit pattern you used in the `if` above (FWIW I prefer this approach myself :))

Answer (score 1):

You can limit when useEffect triggers with the second parameter (array of variables).

```
useEffect(() => true, [variable]);
```

On first load or when variables changes value, the use effect will be triggered, if you dont specify anything as second parameter, every re-render the useEffect will trigger.

Answer (score 1):

To replace `componentDidUpdate` with `useEffect` hook, pass it a second argument with an array of variables that has to be changed from this render to the next in order for the hook to run

```
useEffect(() => {

  // your code

},[props.notifications])
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Just use `props.notifications`.